# The shortest path between two addresses

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

Using google map, you can actually get the different possible routes between two addresses, also you get the length of every possible route.

[image]
I'm now working on a website with  `google map`, i want to calculate the shortest path between two different addresses same as google map does. then get the path length back as javascript variable.

Comment: You can get alternate routes with the Google Maps API v3 DirectionsService.  Each route includes its distance and duration. [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) - [DirectionsService Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest), see provideRouteAlternatives - Whether or not route alternatives should be provided. Optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it can be calculated using google map api called `Distance Matrix` it returns a json response containing  `The recommended path's length` and `Duration`.

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "Témara, Maroc" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Rabat, Maroc" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "13,6 km",
              "value" : 13620
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "23 minutes",
              "value" : 1358
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

This should work fine:

```
function getDistance()
{
var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=rabat&destinations=temara&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false";
var def = new jQuery.Deferred(); 
$.getJSON(url,function(json)
{
if (json.status=="OK")
{
var distance=json.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
}
def.resolve(distance);
});
return def.promise();
}

$.when(getDistance()).then(function(distance){
alert(distance);});
```

[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/9ksqg/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these function:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (latLng1, latLng1);
```

The arguments are two LatLng objects.
Make sure you include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: What' does it return?

Comment: the shortest path straight

Comment: But this calculate the length of the geodesic between the two LatLng object, either a route exists or not.